# Can req.user of passport.js be manipulated?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, post, passport.js

in my api whenever I get a request I check out the req.user._id which is added to any request when you have nodejs using the passportJS authentication middleware.

My question is this: can a hacker send a post request and fill the parameter of req.user._id with an id that doesn't belong to them?

If not, can you please explain why?